# how to add and replace an element of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Lets say I have an array like the one below:

```
let arr = [ {A: 10, B: 25, C; 30, name: John}, {A: 5, B: 15, C; 20, name: John}, 
            {A: 15, B: 22, C; 13, name: John}, {A: 10, B: 34, C; 60, name: John}, 
            {A: 24, B: 5, C; 3, name: Jack}, {A: 15, B: 30, C; 30, name: Jack}, 
            {A: 2, B: 12, C; 37, name: Jil}
]
```

So I am struggling on finding the best way to add all the `A`,`B`,`C` for the objects with the same name. For example I want all objects that have the name John to have `{A: 40, B: 96, C: 123, name: John}.`

The code below was one of my attempt to add the letter that was passed in as the parameter but this resulted in doing it individually and it wasn't really helping solve my issue.

```
addLetters(arr, name, gradeLetter){
    const counter = 0;
    return arr.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
       if (name === cur.name){
         counter = prev + parseInt(cur[gradeLetter]);
       }
       return counter
     }, 0);
}
```

Comment: and A,B,C what are?

Comment: A,B,C are integers. If that is what you are asking

Comment: obviously, but you want all the object that have `name == John` to be `{A: 40, B: 96, C: 123, name: John}`... no?

Comment: correct. I want to add all the A,B,C for objects that have name John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you check for name1 it should be name, I have changed your code a bit and added some explanation

```js
var arr = [ {A: 10, B: 25, C: 30, name: "John"}, {A: 5, B: 15, C: 20, name: "John"}, 
  {A: 15, B: 22, C: 13, name: "John"}, {A: 10, B: 34, C: 60, name: "John"}, 
  {A: 24, B: 5, C: 3, name: "Jack"}, {A: 15, B: 30, C: 30, name: "Jack"}, 
  {A: 2, B: 12, C: 37, name: "Jil"}
]


function addLetters(arr, name){
  return Object.values(arr.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
     if (name === cur.name && !prev[name]){  // check for current name and prev is empty
         prev[name]=cur                 
     }
     else if(name === cur.name && prev[name]) {   // check for prev and name match curr.name
      prev[name] ={...prev[name], A:prev[name].A+cur.A , B: cur.B+prev[name].B,C : cur.C+prev[name].C} // update prev
     }
     return prev
   }, {}));
}
console.log(addLetters(arr, "John"))
```

You could minimise the code above into this

```js
var arx = [ {A: 10, B: 25, C: 30, name: "John"}, {A: 5, B: 15, C: 20, name: "John"}, 
  {A: 15, B: 22, C: 13, name: "John"}, {A: 10, B: 34, C: 60, name: "John"}, 
  {A: 24, B: 5, C: 3, name: "Jack"}, {A: 15, B: 30, C: 30, name: "Jack"}, 
  {A: 2, B: 12, C: 37, name: "Jil"}
]

res= arx.reduce((r,c) => 
{ (!r[c.name])?r[c.name] = c : r[c.name] = {...r[c.name], A : c.A + r[c.name].A , 
 B : c.B + r[c.name].B, C : c.C + r[c.name].C} ; return r} , {})
console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So first, the input example has some errors:

```
let arr = [ {A: 10, B: 25, C: 30, name: 'John'}, {A: 5, B: 15, C: 20, name: 'John'}, 
            {A: 15, B: 22, C: 13, name: 'John'}, {A: 10, B: 34, C: 60, name: 'John'}, 
            {A: 24, B: 5, C: 3, name: 'Jack'}, {A: 15, B: 30, C: 30, name: 'Jack'}, 
            {A: 2, B: 12, C: 37, name: 'Jil'}
]
```

And your code is fine, but `counter` is never defined, instead you should use `prev`, and the property is `name` and not `name1`:

```
addLetters(arr, name, gradeLetter){
    return arr.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
       if (name === cur.name){
//                        ^^^  
         prev = prev + parseInt(cur[gradeLetter]);
//       ^^^^        
       }
       return prev
//            ^^^^
     }, 0);
}
```

And for a "more fit version":

```
addLetters(arr, name, gradeLetter){
    return arr.reduce((prev, cur) => prev + cur[gradeLetter] * (name === cur.name), 0);
}
```

```js
let arr = [ {A: 10, B: 25, C: 30, name: 'John'}, {A: 5, B: 15, C: 20, name: 'John'}, 
            {A: 15, B: 22, C: 13, name: 'John'}, {A: 10, B: 34, C: 60, name: 'John'}, 
            {A: 24, B: 5, C: 3, name: 'Jack'}, {A: 15, B: 30, C: 30, name: 'Jack'}, 
            {A: 2, B: 12, C: 37, name: 'Jil'}
];
let gradeLetter = 'A'
let name = 'John'
console.log(arr.reduce((prev, cur) => prev + cur[gradeLetter] * (name === cur.name), 0));
```

Comment: I understand that I have error in the example I gave above but that is because I gave a different example which was more simplified compared to the array I am dealing with. Thanks for point those out. Will make edit on those.

Answer (score 1):

I would just convert it over into an Object, combining them if you are going to.have to look up more than one.

```js
let arr = [
  {A: 10, B: 25, C: 30, name: 'John'},
  {A:  5, B: 15, C: 20, name: 'John'}, 
  {A: 15, B: 22, C: 13, name: 'John'},
  {A: 10, B: 34, C: 60, name: 'John'}, 
  {A: 24, B:  5, C:  3, name: 'Jack'}, 
  {A: 15, B: 30, C: 30, name: 'Jack'}, 
  {A:  2, B: 12, C: 37, name: 'Jill'}
];


const lookup = arr.reduce(function (lookup, data) {
  if (!lookup[data.name]) {
    lookup[data.name] = Object.assign({}, data);
  } else {
    ['A','B','C'].forEach(function (key) {
      lookup[data.name][key] += data[key];
    });
  }
  return lookup
}, {})

console.log(lookup['John'])
console.log(lookup['John']['A'])
console.log(lookup['Jack']['B'])
```

Comment: This works but I was looking to keep the rest of the data of that object rather than just return the added number.

Comment: oh okay. Didn't see it clearly. Sorry for the mistake. Thanks for helping, really appreciate it!